# Another entities-cannot-be-cast-to-javassist-util-proxy-proxy

Tags: java, gwt, proxy, requestfactory, many-to-one

Following thread [entities cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy, i do have now a server side error ( tks thomas)
I wasn't able to face the real problem within my app.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.nit.persistance.entities.Manufacturers_.$$_javassist_3 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4419)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1017)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:944)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2143)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3939)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1017)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2413)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:913)
    at org.nit.persistance.dao.impl.FichesImpl.readbyPK(FichesImpl.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.readbyPK(Unknown Source)
    at org.nit.server.CEM.CEMFiches.fetch(CEMFiches.java:52)
    at org.nit.server.service.FichesService.fetch(FichesService.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer.invoke(ReflectiveServiceLayer.java:182)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:463)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:233)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)java.lang.ClassCastException: org.nit.persistance.entitesManufacturers_.$$_javassist_3 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4419)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1017)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:944)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2143)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3939)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1017)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2413)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:913)
    at org.nit.persistance.dao.impl.FichesImpl.readbyPK(FichesImpl.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.readbyPK(Unknown Source)
    at org.nit.server.CEM.CEMFiches.fetch(CEMFiches.java:52)
    at org.nit.server.service.FichesService.fetch(FichesService.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer.invoke(ReflectiveServiceLayer.java:182)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:111)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:463)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:233)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

What does this part means ?

```
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.readbyPK(Unknown Source)
at org.nit.server.CEM.CEMFiches.fetch(CEMFiches.java:52)
at org.nit.server.service.FichesService.fetch(FichesService.java:11)
```

Error is on Manufacturers entity, but I am working on Fiches.

- Fiches is linked by a many-to-one relation with References
- References is linked by a many-to-one relation with Products
- Products is linked by a many-to-one relation with Manufacturers.

Could it be a problem with one of my proxies ?

**CEMFiches :** ( Line 52 is return fichesDAO.readbyPK(fichesPK);)

```
 public static Fiches fetch (String metier, String sitegeo, String cptdossier, Integer numligne) {
        if (fichesDAO == null) {
          HttpServletRequest request = RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest();
          ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
          fichesDAO =context.getBean(IFichesDAO.class);

      }
        try {
                FichesPK fichesPK = new FichesPK(metier,sitegeo, cptdossier, numligne);
                return fichesDAO.readbyPK(fichesPK);
            } catch (PersistanceException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
      }
```

**IfichesDAO** is ( @transactional is used )

```
public interface IFichesDAO {
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public void save(Fiches fiches) throws PersistanceException;
    public Fiches readbyPK(FichesPK fichesPK) throws PersistanceException;

}
```

**FichesImpl** is

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Fiches readbyPK(FichesPK fichesPK){
    return (Fiches)getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(Fiches.class, fichesPK);
}
```

**FichesService** :

```
public class FichesService
{
    public Fiches fetch(FichesPK id) { return CEMFiches.fetch(id); }
    public FichesPK fetchPK(FichesPK id) { return CEMFiches.fetchPK(id); }
    public Fiches fetch(String metier, String sitegeo, String cptdossier, Integer numligne) { return CEMFiches.fetch(metier, sitegeo, cptdossier, numligne); }


}
```

Comment: You sure you have the right version of Javassist in the classpath? This error most commonly happens when you have two versions on the classpath and they get into a flight. You should have a single javassist.jar on the classpath with `version >= 3.16`

Comment: @Boris the Spider
You were absolutely right ! had javassist-3.1 and javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
I did remove 3.1 as you suggested and it works perfectly.
Thanks a ton !

Comment: Worked for me too. The duplication happened after upgrading Spring and Hibernate.

Answer (score 5):

I also hit this issue while attempting to render an entity as JSON using Spring's @ResponseBody annotation. The issue turned out to be a relationship annotated as @ManyToOne with a FetchType of LAZY. The error message was not at all helpful. Switching to EAGER fetch solved the problem.

It may be helpful to note that in my case, the target entity also had a relationship of @ManyToOne which was recursive (target table had a foreign key to itself) which was also mapped as LAZY. Both relationships had to be switched to EAGER to get the problem resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error and the strange thing is that all the other entities in my project run ok, except one. According to `Boris the Spider's suggestion`, I checked my project and found that there is a jar called weld-osgi-bundle.jar(in the`Java EE 6` Libraries, provided by `myEclipse10.0)` contains some javassist code which may be conflict with javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar`in my web libraries. So I removed it, and the problem gets solved.`

Answer (score 2):

So I ran into this issue, and I thought I would add some additional details for those who might have the same problem.

I had a collection of dependencies, and one imported `org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA`, while the other imported `javassist:javassist:3.11.0.GA`.

Because of the different groups (it would seem that `javassist:javassist` became `org.javassist:javassist`), the build tool wasn't excluding one in favour of the other, and my WAR file had both.

I had to manually exclude the old javassist dependency, and once it was removed everything was fine.